# booting into recovery mode = fail

Tags: recovery-mode

The story so far...

Several weeks ago 12.04 crashed while i was on the interweb. Now when i boot, it asks me for a password to log in. I can log in as a guest, but of course all my files and documents are inaccessible to the guest. 
I have followed the instructions on the wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode, but at step 7 there is no message saying "Drop to root shell prompt". Instead it reads:
"root@clayton-desktop:~# [   29.606190] tda10048_firmware_upload: Upload failed. (file not found?)"
And there is a flashing cursor below.

Any thoughts?

Clayton

P.S. Even though I have been using ubuntu hassle free for many years, I am quite ICT challenged.

Answer (score 0):

Hah, you have a root shell already. Type `passwd *insert-your-username-here*`, and enter a new password.

Comment: Now have a new password, but can't get past the log in page. I enter the password in the box under my user name and it just brings me back to the same place. Tried it in recovery console, ubuntu, ubuntu 2D, and user defined session. All the same result.

Comment: Did you type exactly `passwd clayton`?

Comment: pretty sure i did because if i type anything else in the space it tells me in red "invalid password, please try again." whereas typing in clayton makes the monitor go blank temporarily and come back to the same login screen.

Comment: Next step: try doing the same procedure, but instead of typing passwd, type `adduser test-user --group sudo`, and type in a password for it. Now you can login as test-user which is an Admin account.

Comment: keeps coming back to root@clayton-desktop:~#and a flashing cursor. The error message is : "adduser: The user 'test-user-group' does not exist. I tried it with 2 dashes between user and group also for the same result.